# Encriptado diferente en SQL

Tags: sql, encriptación, tsql

tengo una tabla(Users) con 2 filas

```
nameUser como varchar(50)
passUser como varbinary(200)
```

La cuestion es que estoy metiendo datos de prueba para despues procesarlos pero he notado que metiendo la misma contraseña la encriptacion da diferente, por ejemplo, para insertar valores estoy usando esta linea de codigo:

```
INSERT INTO Users(nameUser, passUser)VALUES('gato', 
EncryptbyPassphrase('keySecret','perro'))
```

pero cuando muestro la tabla sale esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

SI estoy usando la misma clave(keySecret) y el mismo texto (perro), no me tienen que dar exactamente lo mismo?

Tambien estoy tratando (según yo), de hacer un SELECT validando que el pass sea igual a lo que se ingresa

```
SELECT nameUser
FROM Users
WHERE passUser=EncryptbyPassphrase('keySecret','perro')
```

Agradeceria saber porque no da igual el mismo `EncryptbyPassphrase`.

Comment: ya intento traer los registros he imprimirlo a ver que valores te da ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La naturaleza de `EncryptbyPassphrase` es No determinística, es decir cada vez que la invoques, aunque uses los mismo parámetros el resultado va a ser distinto:

```
SELECT  EncryptbyPassphrase('Mi frase secreta','perro')
-- Output 0x01000000424CE2500564F0FF5614419368F0BCBC9D5379A91F7744C7
SELECT  EncryptbyPassphrase('Mi frase secreta','perro')
-- Output 0x01000000D18F1C9DD9FF90AE115FA57A321872BA89F9A3913A7D7E8B
```

Y esto se debe a la naturaleza del cifrado (TRIPLE DES algorithm with a 128 key bit length.) que aporta un mecanismo más seguro. En algoritmos básicos, obtendrías siempre el mismo resultado para una misma contraseña y dato a cifrar, lo que hace mucho más fácil el ataque del mismo y por consiguiente mucho más débil el algoritmo.

Esta naturaleza no determinística conlleva el inconveniente que no puedes comparar los valores cifrados directamente, deberías descifrarlos en primer lugar, por ejemplo:

```
SELECT nameUser
       FROM Users
       WHERE EncryptbyPassphrase('keySecret',passUser) = EncryptbyPassphrase('keySecret','perro')
```

O mucho mejor:

```
SELECT nameUser
       FROM Users
       WHERE DecryptByPassphrase('keySecret',passUser) = 'perro'
```

De todas formas, cifrar las contraseñas para guardarlas en la base de datos no es la mejor idea, te roban la tabla y te robaron todas las contraseñas. Lo que se estila, es guardar un HASH, es decir un número que representa la contraseña pero no la contiene, los procesos de autentificación entonces solo comparan estos números. Te dejo algún enlace adicional por si te interesa:

- [Storing passwords in a secure way in a SQL Server database](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4037/storing-passwords-in-a-secure-way-in-a-sql-server-database/)
- [Hash Algorithms – How does SQL Server store Passwords?](https://sqlity.net/en/2460/sql-password-hash/)